# Node.js & sql server & python?

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I want to run SQL server query  . ( under NodeJs server)

I've read [**here**](https://npmjs.org/package/node-sqlserver)  About the Prerequisites

Question :

Why Node.js required Python ?

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the image you've posted answers the question. The comment beside Python is "for node-gyp" and indeed the [installation documentation](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) for node-gyp includes Python as a pre-requisite.

Comment: @Pondlife Well , I didnt know that node-gyp has anything to do with it , because I dont know what is it and especially how it is realted to sql. and I already found a solution using tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node doesn't require Python. It's a requirement of the SQL driver you want to use.

Comment: Can I connect to sql server via node Without python ?

Comment: Well, if "sql server" means any SQL server you can use something like this for MySQL: https://npmjs.org/package/mysql. If you want to use Microsoft SQL you'll need it. Python is used by node-gyp which is used by the driver for some build processes. I don't think it's possible without Python. Is this a problem for you?

Comment: Sebastian Thanks :-) no it is not a problem . I just wanted the reason. ( and I only need mssql server).